# Ember Js testing a service with promises

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-testing

How to test a method inside a service that returns a store in Ember Unit Test using qunit

```js
export default Ember.Service.extend({

store: Ember.inject.service(),

    setSomeProps() {
        this.get('store').find('somemodel', id)
          .then((someData) => {
            this.set('someProp', someDate.get('name'));
          });
    }

});
```

The setSomeProps is a method inside my service, I am fairly new to ember and cannot get my head around ember unit test. Whats the best way to write a unit test for this function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock the `store` service in your unit test of `store-caller-service`.
You should use `wait` function for asynchronous test behaviour which is described [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/testing/testing-components/#toc_waiting-on-asynchronous-behavior).

Take a look at this [twiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/cdc398b6cd5b49fc0003c02c280a1168?openFiles=tests.unit.services.store-caller-test.js%2C)

Comment: Thanks for creating a really good twiddle demonstrating the solution. If only more answers could be as good as that!